# Two xs:key same as composite key?

Tags: xml, xsd, key, xsd-validation

I am working with [this schema](http://www.aed.public.lu/FAIA/FAIA/FAIA_v_2_01_full.xsd), and noticed the following in the key section:

```
    <xs:key name="KeyAnalysisType">
        <xs:selector xpath="MasterFiles/AnalysisTypeTable/AnalysisTypeTableEntry"/>
        <xs:field xpath="AnalysisType"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:key name="KeyAnalysisID">
        <xs:selector xpath="MasterFiles/AnalysisTypeTable/AnalysisTypeTableEntry"/>
        <xs:field xpath="AnalysisID"/>
    </xs:key>
```

Both keys are referring to this section:

```
<xs:element name="AnalysisTypeTable" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AnalysisTypeTableEntry" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="AnalysisType" type="FAIAcodeType">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation>Analysis type identifier: e.g. CC (for Cost Center), DEP (for department), etc.</xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="AnalysisTypeDescription" type="FAIAlongtextType">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation>Description of the AnalysisType, e.g. "Cost Center"</xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="AnalysisID" type="FAIAmiddle1textType">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation>Analysis ID: e.g. 1200-HDOF-TR (for cost center treasury in the headoffice) </xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="AnalysisIDDescription" type="FAIAlongtextType">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation>Description of the AnalysisID: e.g. "Headoffice-Treasury".</xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Would this double key definition work in the same way as a composite key selecting for both fields? E.g.

```
<xs:key name="CompositeKeyAnalysis">
    <xs:selector xpath="MasterFiles/AnalysisTypeTable/AnalysisTypeTableEntry"/>
    <xs:field xpath="AnalysisID"/>
    <xs:field xpath="AnalysisType"/>
</xs:key>
```

Answer (score 1):

The double key definition differs in an important aspect
from the composite key. Take this example document:

```
<root>
    <item key1="A" key2="a"/>
    <item key1="B" key2="b"/>

    <reference ref1="A" ref2="a"/>
    <reference ref1="B" ref2="b"/>
</root>
```

And lets define separate keys for the `key1` and `key2` nodes:

```
<xs:key name="Key1">
    <xs:selector xpath="item"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@key1"/>
</xs:key>
<xs:key name="Key2">
    <xs:selector xpath="item"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@key2"/>
</xs:key>

<xs:keyref name="Keyref1" refer="Key1">
    <xs:selector xpath="reference"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@ref1"/>
</xs:keyref>
<xs:keyref name="Keyref2" refer="Key2">
    <xs:selector xpath="reference"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@ref2"/>
</xs:keyref>
```

In this case, the keys are matched separately,
without knowledge of each other. Consequently, a `<reference>` element is allowed to reference the keys of different `<item>` elements, which might or might not be intended:

```
<root>
    <item key1="A" key2="a"/>
    <item key1="B" key2="b"/>

    <reference ref1="A" ref2="b"/> <!-- Mix of "A" and "b" -->
    <reference ref1="B" ref2="a"/> <!-- Mix of "B" and "a" -->
</root>
```

If on the other hand a composite key is used, the above document
would be invalid. Because then the keys are matched as a group,
and a `<reference>` element must refer to a single `<item>` element that
matches *both* keys (as in the first example):

```
<xs:key name="Key12">
    <xs:selector xpath="item"/>
    <!-- Both fields belong to the same <item> element -->
    <xs:field xpath="@key1"/> 
    <xs:field xpath="@key2"/>
</xs:key>

<xs:keyref name="Keyref12" refer="Key12">
    <xs:selector xpath="reference"/>
    <!-- Both fields belong to the same <reference> element -->
    <xs:field xpath="@ref1"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@ref2"/>
</xs:keyref>
```

Comment: Can you think of a reason why such a deisgn would be used? As far as I understand the design with two separate keys prevent you from creating entries combining the two keys, e.g. 1 - red, 1 - blue, as each key has to be unique on its own. A composite key would on the other hand admit these combinations, as only the whole composite key would have to be unique.

Comment: On possible use case for your separate key example is when the keys are referenced individually in other parts of the document, e.g. `<reference ref1="A"/>`. This is not possible with composite keys.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't guarantee that it's absolutely equivalent in all cases, e.g. when one of the fields is present and the other is absent. But in normal cases, where both fields are present, I think the two constructs are equivalent.

Comment: Hi Mike, I'm probably missing something here, but isn't it the case that, for example, if there are four nodes with (ID, type) respectively (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3) and (2, 4), the instance would be valid against to the composite key as all tuples are unique, but not against any of two keys separately (duplicate 1s, etc)?